# How to disable or turn off iOS background location capability

Tags: ios, background, location

On iOS 8, I can enable background location service with the capability set.
My app can receive location update in background mode, and when in background mode there is a blue bar on top to indicate the background location service is running.

The app is using Google MAP Service plus CLLocationManager.

**Question**:
Can I turn off background capability in run time?

Description
I want to enable / disable this background location service in app's setting page. 
Somehow I've tried stopUpdatingLocation, but in background the blue bar still exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the answer.

When an app is enabled background location service and you want to disable it at run time, you will need:

1. Release all CLLocationManager in your app when entering background mode.
2. Set your GMSMapView .myLocationEnabled to NO